# Compression Plus data format?

Tags: .net, sql-server, compression

I have been handed a database whose format dates to the 1990s and was apparently first created as MDB format before moving to SQL Server. Not a problem, except for one thing... a number of tables have columns that hold monthly data for 20 years of data, one double/float per month. The data in the field(s) has been "compressed" and stored as a hex string.

There is a related application which no longer runs, but helpfully coughs up an error about a missing DLL, CompPl32.dll. Poking about, [it appears this was a 1996 compression library](https://api.256file.com/comppl32.dll/m-download-429710.html) from a company called EllTech, long gone. Although the DLL is available for download I'd rather avoid it. Is anyone familiar with the format and have suggestions on how to uncompress it? Here is a sample of the data in the DB:

```
CompressedLen  UncompressedLen  Data
18             3080             EDC08100000000C2B0FCA903F936000020E70000
```

If the 18 is to be believed, the first 32 bits are not part of the data. The first two characters are "ED" in every field.

Comment: Compressing 3080 bytes of data down to 18 doesn't really seem believable except if it has a ton of repetition maybe

Comment: The "hex string" is probably a `varbinary` column. Storing something as a hex string takes one byte and converts it to two characters so doesn't help with space savings.

Comment: Compression Plus was a utility for working with .arj, .lha and .zip files so it's unlikely to be using any advanced algorithms created after PKZIP 2.04G. Not really helpful, I know, but at least limits the scope in the search for possible decompression routines.

Comment: @MartinSmith Indeed, it turns out to be 3080 zero bytes compressed to 18 bytes.

Comment: @MartinSmith - most of the data is very sparce, normally 90% of the entries are zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the compressed data is simply raw deflate, where the binary data is encoded in hexadecimal. Indeed the first 18 bytes after converting the hex to binary is a valid and complete raw deflate stream, and it decompresses to 3080 bytes. Specifically 3080 bytes that are all zeros.

You can use the [DeflateStream class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.deflatestream) to decompress the raw deflate data.

I have no idea why there are two extraneous zero bytes after the 18 bytes of deflate data. Perhaps they felt compelled to round it out to a multiple of four.

Comment: Excellent work Mark, I'm going to code this up now.